# PHP check number in database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check if number in database is 1 or 0, and which number it is from beggining, for example, in my SQL column I have information like this:

```
0 0 0 1 0
```

And it has number 1 in it's SQL, and it's the fourth number from beginning, and I need to loop through all variables and check where is and what is this number, code something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $<5; $i++) {
    while(//what to do here?) {
        //Code
    }
}
```

And, more examples:

```
if($Array[$i] == 1) { //Checks if the number is 1
    echo "The number 1 in your column is at position:". $Variable .";
```

Shows where is the number from the beggining, in this case it is 4.
So, thanks for help, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither tutorial site, free workforce nor web search replacement. We can help you on [some topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on the subject in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/). If you think you did that, read [how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You should really start by properly normalizing your data structure, as you have already been advised in your previous question about this same issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554719/php-check-image-and-database-for-matches

Answer (score 0):

Well, I readed your comments, and tried to do this myself, and I did, here is how I done this:

```
    else {
        $arr = explode(" ", $row["skins"]);
        for($a = 0; $a < count($arr); $a++) {
            if($arr[$a] == 1) {
                //Rest of the code
            }
        }
    }
```

It's not full code, but it works. Thanks for your support, and your motivation that I can do it myself :)